# Why is tqdm only updating after multiple iterations?

Tags: python, printing, tqdm

I'm using tqdm twice in my script, and the first time it works fine but the second time it only updates after 14 iterations. It's the same if I remove all other print statements. Any idea what might be going wrong?

Program:

```
for name in tqdm(final_urls):
    print(f"Downloading {name} files...")
    url_list = final_urls[name]
    class_dir = os.path.join("data", name)

    if not os.path.isdir(class_dir):
        os.mkdir(class_dir)

    for idx, url in enumerate(url_list):
        filepath = os.path.join(class_dir, f"audio{idx}.wav")
        if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
            r = requests.get(url)
            with open(filepath, "wb+") as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

Output:

```
Download files...
  0%|                                                                                                                   | 0/32 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Downloading Bearded Seal files...
Downloading Bottlenose Dolphin files...
Downloading Rough-Toothed Dolphin files...
Downloading Common Dolphin files...
Downloading Striped Dolphin files...
Downloading Fin, Finback Whale files...
Downloading Melon Headed Whale files...
Downloading Killer Whale files...
Downloading False Killer Whale files...
Downloading Spinner Dolphin files...
Downloading Ross Seal files...
Downloading Harp Seal files...
Downloading Northern Right Whale files...
Downloading Short-Finned (Pacific) Pilot Whale files...
 44%|██████████████████████████████████████████████▍                                                           | 14/32 [01:34<02:01,  6.74s/it]Downloading White-beaked Dolphin files...
Downloading Narwhal files...
Downloading Humpback Whale files...
Downloading Walrus files...
Downloading Fraser's Dolphin files...
Downloading Beluga, White Whale files...
Downloading Clymene Dolphin files...
Downloading Southern Right Whale files...
Downloading Atlantic Spotted Dolphin files...
Downloading Leopard Seal files...
Downloading Long-Finned Pilot Whale files...
Downloading Grampus, Risso's Dolphin files...
Downloading Sperm Whale files...
Downloading Pantropical Spotted Dolphin files...
Downloading Bowhead Whale files...
Downloading Minke Whale files...
Downloading White-sided Dolphin files...
Downloading Weddell Seal files...
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 32/32 [01:34<00:00,  2.95s/it]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tqdm doesn't, by default, show every single update if the updates happen fast; by default it only updates 10 times per second. You can set the `miniters` parameter to `1` if you must have the output update on every iteration.

The default is `miniters=None`, which means it'll dynamically adjust the iteration count based on `mininterval`, which is set to `0.1` seconds.

You are also using `print()`, which *replaces* the bar output. Don't do that, updates will be overwritten and you get very messy output.

The `tqdm` class has a dedicated [`tqdm.write()` method](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#write), use that instead:

```
for name in tqdm(final_urls):
    tqdm.write(f"Downloading {name} files...")
```

Using the method lets tqdm take care of how the messages are placed, as per the documentation:

> Print a message via tqdm (without overlap with bars).

Quick demo to show the difference, while using `miniters=1`:

```
>>> from tqdm import tqdm
>>> from faker import Faker
>>> import time, random
>>> for word in tqdm(Faker().words(10), ncols=40, miniters=1):
...     print(f"Using print: {word}")
...     time.sleep(random.random() * .2)
...
  0%|            | 0/10 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Using print: of
 10%|▍   | 1/10 [00:00<00:01,  5.02it/s]Using print: we
 20%|▊   | 2/10 [00:00<00:01,  5.52it/s]Using print: message
 30%|█▏  | 3/10 [00:00<00:01,  5.83it/s]Using print: win
Using print: seem
 50%|██  | 5/10 [00:00<00:00,  9.12it/s]Using print: especially
 60%|██▍ | 6/10 [00:00<00:00,  8.00it/s]Using print: power
 70%|██▊ | 7/10 [00:00<00:00,  8.42it/s]Using print: material
Using print: both
 90%|███▌| 9/10 [00:01<00:00,  8.27it/s]Using print: single
100%|███| 10/10 [00:01<00:00,  8.09it/s]
>>> for word in tqdm(Faker().words(10), ncols=40, miniters=1):
...     tqdm.write(f"Using tqdm.write: {word}")
...     time.sleep(random.random() * .2)
...
Using tqdm.write: democratic
Using tqdm.write: manage
Using tqdm.write: generation
Using tqdm.write: perhaps
Using tqdm.write: purpose
Using tqdm.write: about
Using tqdm.write: evidence
Using tqdm.write: everything
Using tqdm.write: push
Using tqdm.write: large
100%|███| 10/10 [00:01<00:00,  7.65it/s]
```

and, still using `tqdm.write()`, `miniters=1` in progress:

[image: Animated GIF image of a terminal screen with progress bar progressing from 0 to 100 percent]

Comment: Even without the print statement the bar stays stuck at 0

Comment: @ShreyJoshi: are you *nesting* the tqdm objects?

Comment: no, sorry i forgot to post the earlier part of the script where i used the first tqdm

Comment: @ShreyJoshi: you'll need to give us a proper [mcve] if you want us to diagnose issues properly. Give us something that we can copy and paste to reproduce the issue, please.